# Understanding Lay's Proof of Uniqueness of Reduced Echelon Form

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

In Lay's Linear Algebra and Its applications, he gives a proof the uniqueness of the reduced echelon form.

Consider two row equivalent matrices U and V in reduced echelon form. He says that the pivot columns of U and V are precisely the nonzero columns that are not linearly dependent to the columns to their left. Since U and V are row equivalent, their columns have the same linear dependence relations. **Hence, the pivot columns of U and V appear in the same locations.**

I'm having a hard time seeing how the bolded statement follows from the previous two statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that the $k$-th column of $U$ is a pivot column; then it is linearly independent of the columns to its left. If the $k$-th column of $V$ were **not** linearly independent of the columns to its left, it would be linear combination of them, and the first $k$ columns of $V$ would therefore satisfy a linear dependence relation that the first $k$ columns of $U$ do not satisfy. But that is impossible, because $U$ and $V$ are row-equivalent, and their columns therefore satisfy the same linear independence relations: if the first $k$ columns of $V$ are linearly dependent, then so are the first $k$ columns of $U$, and vice versa.

Therefore the $k$-th column of $V$ must be linearly independent of the columns to its left and hence be a pivot column. This shows that every pivot column of $U$ must be a pivot column of $V$, and the same argument with the rôles of $U$ and $V$ reversed shows that every pivot column of $V$ must be a pivot column of $U$. It follows that $U$ and $V$ must have exactly the same pivot columns.

Comment: Why is that a column linearly independent of the columns to its left necessarily is a pivot column?

Comment: @SerendipitousEpiphany: When it is linearly **dependent** of the columns to its left, it necessarily has a $0$ in every row in which they all have $0$: its non-zero entries are in rows in which at least one of them also has a non-zero entry. If you think about the reduction procedure, you’ll see that this means that there is no pivot element in that column. If, on the other hand, the column is linearly **independent** of the columns to its left, there will be a row in which they all have $0$ and it has something else, meaning that it has a pivot element.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I don't know what I was thinking, I'm getting rid of my comment (and this one soon)